# String replace regex with Case sensitive

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace all matching occurrences of 'searchString' from 'targetString'
(maintaining their case from targetString) with `<span class="xyz">searchString</span>` in JAVA

For example - 
targetString - "Super Sports"
searchString - "s" and "S" and "Sp" and "SP" and "Sr"
Resulting targetString should be -

for  "s" - `<span>S</span>uper <span>S</span>port<span>s</span>`

for "S" - `<span>S</span>uper <span>S</span>port<span>s</span>`

for "Sp" - `Super <span>Sp</span>orts`

I've done it in Javascript- but need it in Java -

```
var applyHighlighting = function(productFilterKeyword) {
            if (productFilterKeyword != "") {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.highlightableElements.length; i++) {
                    var regexp = new RegExp(productFilterKeyword, 'ig');
                    $scope.highlightableElements[i].sourceHTML = $scope.highlightableElements[i].innerHTML;
                    $scope.highlightableElements[i].innerHTML = $scope.highlightableElements[i].sourceHTML.replace(regexp, '<span style="background-color: yellow">$&</span>');
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So, you just want to search case insensitive and then use data that was found in a new string without any changes to it?

Comment: Do you really need regex or is it allways just plain text? It seems, you just exchanges X througth <span style="background-color: yellow">X</span>.

Comment: @TEXHIK Yes- That's how I want to implement

Comment: I get 'searchString' and 'targetString' as plain text.

Comment: In that case all you need is  oldValue.replace(productFilterKeyword, "<span style=\"background-color: yellow\">"+productFilterKeyword+"</span>");   [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

Comment: @Mikey - but what if productFilterKeyword is lowercase and match from oldValue is upperCase ?

Comment: @Devendra W it is case sensitive ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96214/discussion-between-devendra-w-and-mikey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of details, you have post in comments, it is not as hard as you thinsk.

Just replace all of mathces to span them_self span:

```
  String original, result, regex;
  String your_search_string = "S";//for example
  original = .....
  regex = "(" + your_search_string + ")";
  result = original.replaceAll(regex, "<span>$1</span>");
```

`$1` in java regex is link to a group. the zero group `$0` is a whole regex.

Comment: from examples it have to be case insensitive : add (?i) for case insensitive to regex. regex = "(" + your_search_string + ")(?i)";

Comment: $0 is working for me - Thanks @TEXHIK - but one more problem is that <span>text</span> is getting rendered as &lt;span&gt;text&lt;/span&gt; on my HTML - I want <span> tag to be rendered as normal HTML tag. How can be achieved this  ?

Comment: @DevendraW how to you transfer result from java to your html?

Comment: over REST service call

Comment: Check, how you are returning, it seems, that java thinks that it is text to display, not html.